# How to replace one element from a list with several element from another list?

Tags: python

There is 2 list:

```
list_a = [['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry'], ['meat'], ['milk'], ['meat']]
list_b = [['chicken'], ['pork'], ['beef']]
```

How can I put list_b to list_a instead of 'meat' like this:

```
list_c = [['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry'], ['chicken'], ['pork'],
['beef'], ['milk'], ['chicken'], ['pork'], ['beef']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a a for loop and the .extend() list method:

```
for food in list_a:
    if food == ['meat']:
        list_c.extend(list_b)
    else:
        list_c.append(food)

print (list_c)
```

And `list_c` will print out:

```
[['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry'], ['chicken'], ['pork'], ['beef'], ['milk'], ['chicken'], ['pork'], ['beef']]
```

This way you replace every instance of `['meat']` in `list_a` with all the elements in `list_b`. This will produce exactly the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Slice-assign.

```
>>> list_c = list_a[:]
>>> list_c[-1:] = list_b[:]
>>> list_c
[['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry'], ['chicken'], ['pork'], ['beef']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> idx = list_a.index(['meat'])
>>> list_c = list_a[:idx] + list_b + list_a[idx + 1:]
[['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry'], ['chicken'], ['pork'], ['beef'], ['milk']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def replace(index, L1, L2):
    return L1[0:index] + L2 + L1[index+1:]
```

Just use `slice`.

Answer (score 1):

for your last change..:

```
list_a = [['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry'], ['meat'], ['milk'], ['meat']]
list_b = [['chicken'], ['pork'], ['beef']] 
list_c = []
for x in list_a:
    if x == ["meat"]:
        for y in list_b:
            list_c.append(y)
    else:
        list_c.append(x)

list_c
[['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry'], ['chicken'], ['pork'], ['beef'], ['milk'], ['chicken'], ['pork'], ['beef']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_a = [['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry'], ['meat'], ['milk']]
list_b = [['chicken'], ['pork'], ['beef']]

deletitem = ['meat']

def newlist(deletetemlist,list_a,list_b):
    deletitemidx = list_a.index(deletetemlist)
    print(list_a[:deletitemidx] + list_b + list_a[deletitemidx + 1:])

newlist(deletitem,list_a,list_b)
```

Comment: @AKS, Thanks and modified it